# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I am new to retrofit and I stumbled upon a problem when trying to parse json inside of my application. It looks something like this:

`{ "status": "success", "message": "Data selected from database", "data": [ { "id": "4622", "name": "xyz" } ] }`

Anyways, its a json inside of json, and my program crashes at this exact line, when I parse just part of the json that isn't nested, it works (status and message part).
The app crashes at this exact line:
viewModel.getPost()

I have two data classes that I use, one is called Post and in it I hold the values of status and message, and data, but whenever I try to use the Data part of the Post class, the program crashes and I get
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 69 path $.data error.
I tried to look online but haven't found any solutions that worked for me in kotlin.
Here are my data classes:

```
data class Post(
val status:String,
val message:String,
val data: Data) 

data class Data (
val id : String ,
val name : String)
```

Here is my retrofit api:

```
object RetrofitInstance {

private val retrofit by lazy{
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
val api:SimpleApi by lazy{
    retrofit.create(SimpleApi::class.java)
}}

interface SimpleApi {
@GET("token/username")
suspend fun getPost(): Response<Post>}
```

Post repo:

```
class Repository {
suspend fun getPost(): Response<Post> {
    return  RetrofitInstance.api.getPost()
}}
```

And viewModel files I am using:

```
class MainViewModel(private val repository:Repository): ViewModel() {

val myResponse:MutableLiveData<Response<Post>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getPost(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response=repository.getPost()
        myResponse.value=response
    }
}}

class MainViewModelFactory(private val repository: Repository):ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T{
    return MainViewModel(repository) as T
}}
```

This is the code in which im using the above in the activity:

```
 val repository=Repository()
    val viewModelFactory=MainViewModelFactory(repository)
    viewModel=ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.getPost()
    viewModel.myResponse.observe(this, Observer { response->
        if(response.isSuccessful && response.body()!=null){
            Log.d("Response", response.body().toString())
            Log.d("Response",response.body()?.message.toString())
            Toast.makeText(this, response.body()?.data!!.id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Error response",response.errorBody().toString())
            Toast.makeText(this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        //Toast.makeText(this, response.data.id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    })
```

Any ideas what could I do to get the Data part right so I can work with it in the application?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change type of data in Post Class to List

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think I would need a list of Data objects in Post class because I only had one Data object in my JSON file, but this solved the problem. For those who may find it useful later, code related to response in my main activity looks like this: `if(response.isSuccessful && response.body()!=null){
                Log.d("Response", response.body().toString())
                Log.d("Response",response.body()?.message.toString())
                for(post in response.body()!!.data)
                    Log.d("Response",post.id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "status": "success", "message": "Data selected from database", "data": [ { "id": "4622", "name": "xyz" } ] }
```

in this json **data** is accepting **list of object:**

```
data": [ { "id": "4622", "name": "xyz" } ]
```

but you are having:

```
data class Post(
val status:String,
val message:String,
val data: Data)
```

convert it to:

```
data class Post(
val status:String,
val message:String,
val data: List<Data)
```